# what should the ContentType header be for svg images

Tags: php, svg, http-headers

I want to create images in SVG dynamically (using server-side PHP).  That means the information that this is a SVG image is not contained in the filetype (extension), so I need to tell the browser that this is an SVG -- presumably via the ContentType header.  What value should I put there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The MIME type for SVG is `"image/svg+xml"` ...

[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html#MIMEType)